# ntop not reporting on all interfaces

Tags: interface, ntop

I'm trying to setup ntop on our machine to see which traffic per IP address on our machine, our machines usually have a /28 allocation and this is configured correctly within CetnOS however ntop is only reporting on the first 7 on them. (eth1:1-8) its missing the others.

How can I go about fixing this so that ntop reports on all interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit '/var/lib/ntop/init.cfg'

sample:

```
cat /var/lib/ntop/init.cfg
USER="ntop"
INTERFACES="interface1 interface2"
```

[edited]

Maybe you might try this (from the ntop manpage):

> 2 -i --interface Specifies the network interface or interfaces to be used by ntop for network monitoring.

If multiple interfaces are used (this feature is available only if ntop is compiled with thread support) their names must be separated with a comma. For instance -i "eth0,lo".

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it.

Comment: Please check the new content i added.

Comment: How do we compile ntop with thread support? Plus, does it mean we can only watch one interface otherwise?